# Ubuntu: Problem upgrading from Jaunty to Karmic

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, ubuntu-9.04

When i try to upgrade from jaunty to karmic i get this problem:

```
root@server:~# sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new ubuntu release
Done Upgrade tool signature
Done Upgrade tool
Done downloading
extracting 'lucid.tar.gz'
authenticate 'lucid.tar.gz' against 'lucid.tar.gz.gpg'
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade

An upgrade from 'jaunty' to 'lucid' is not supported with this tool.
```

I have no idea why it tries to upgrade to lucid when i need to upgrade to karmic first. I guess it gets the word "lucid" from somewhere but i have no idea where to start looking.

Comment: Very odd that it was trying to upgrade directly from jaunty to lucid, skipping karmic.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it. Turns out that /etc/update-manager/meta-release is pointing to http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release and that file says:

```
Dist: karmic
Name: Karmic Koala
Version: 9.10
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2009 12:00:00 UTC
Supported: 0
Description: This is the 9.10 release
Release-File: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic/Release
ReleaseNotes: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/EOLReleaseAnnouncement
UpgradeTool: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-proposed/main/dist-upgrader-all/0.126.9/karmic.tar.gz
UpgradeToolSignature: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-proposed/main/dist-upgrader-all/0.126.9/karmic.tar.gz.gpg
```

I downloaded the file, changed "Supported: 0" to "Supported: 1" and hosted the file on my own webserver and pointed the meta-release to my server instead. Worked perfectly.

Don't know if there is a reason Ubuntu wants to make it impossible to do this upgrade or if accidentally changed supported to 0.

Comment: change "Supported: 0" to "Supported: 1" and change all "archive.ubuntu.com" to "old-releases.ubuntu.com"

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
mkdir -pv /tmp/karmic
cd /tmp/karmic
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-proposed/main/dist-upgrader-all/0.126.9/karmic.tar.gz
tar zxvf karmic.tar.gz
./karmic
```

reboot and then:

```
do-release-upgrade
```